# Trying to learn functions in shell

Tags: function, shell

Just trying to learn shell on my Mac and I keep getting this error when I am trying to write functions:

*unexpected token near '('*

Could it be my OSX since it's a Linux shell tutorial(Linuxcommand.org)? I am using bash.

```
alias l='ls -l'

today()

{
    echo -n "Today's date is: "
    date +"%A, %B, %-d, %Y"
}
```

Comment: The bash on Mac should behave the same as the bash on Linux when it comes to such fundamental things.

Comment: Made a huge mistake.

The first troubleshooting I didn't do was restarting my Terminal... everything works fine now...

Answer (score 0):

The way to call a function in bash is to just specify it's name. Like so:

```
today
```

There's no need for `()`. See this [BASH Programming HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) for more examples.

Comment: I get the error when I try to source the file, I know it's already a function, I am following the tutorial and it tells me to:

Shell Functions

Aliases are good for very simple commands, but if you want to create something more complex, you should try shell functions . Shell functions can be thought of as "scripts within scripts" or little sub-scripts. Let's try one. Open .bashrc with your text editor again and replace the alias for "today" with the following:


today() {
    echo -n "Today's date is: "
    date +"%A, %B %-d, %Y"
}

Comment: Try with function today { instead of today() {